# Nokogiri: node_set.rb:239: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am currently crawling some RSS feeds and collecting items into a nodeset. This works great, however Nokogiri crashes with some items. At first I thought something was wrong with my OSX development environment, so installed a Debian server and got the exact same error. Also tried downgrading Ruby from 1.9.3 to 1.9.2.

Any suggestions?

Some of the code:

```
doc.xpath("//item").remove
nodeset = doc.xpath("//item")
..
api_doc.xpath("//item").each do |node|
  node = check_score(node)
  unless node.nil?
    nodeset << node
  end
end

def check_score(node)
  if node.xpath('website:attr[@name="imdbscore"]/@value').text.to_i > 6
    return node
  end
end

# sorting and finally add nodeset to doc.
```

[Crash log here..](http://pastebin.com/73J6HZa7)

Comment: what does `#check_score` do ?

Comment: returns the node if the score passes a filter. return node if node.xpath('website:attr[@name="imdbscore"]/@value').text.to_f > 6 Tried without the check_score method - same problem.

Comment: It'd help if we saw some sample XML that demonstrates the problem. Also, don't link to the crash log, summarize the important information in your question so we can refer to it quickly, rather than make us chase it down just to help you. Finally, what version of Nokogiri are you using, plus what version of LibXML2?

Comment: Okay, thought a crashdump would be useful with such a problem :/

Comment: Using gist or a source-code only paste-site is preferable to using pastebin.com. That particular site hosts lots of stuff that companies ban, so everything posted there is unreachable.

Comment: Will do that next time :) Thanks for letting me know btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's bad practice to remove all the `//item` nodes, then try to find them. Right there I can see trouble brewing.

This deletes all `<item>` nodes from the document:

```
doc.xpath("//item").remove
```

This tries to find all `<item>` nodes, which will return an empty NodeSet:

```
nodeset = doc.xpath("//item")
```

You don't show where `api_doc` comes from, but if it's a Node that came from `doc`, especially from before you removed the nodes, its state is suspicious because you might have some dangling references to removed `<item>` nodes. As is, this tries to loop over all `<item>` nodes, which might not exist, so an empty NodeSet could be returned, or worse, could be damaged:

```
api_doc.xpath("//item").each do |node|
  node = check_score(node)
  unless node.nil?
    nodeset << node
  end
end
```

I'd check the revisions for your Nokogiri and LibXML2 and make sure they're current. If not, update them. I'd also rethink the logic of removing all the `<item>` nodes before you look for them.

Perhaps we could help you better if you explained what you're trying to do, and shared a small example of the XML.

Comment: Problem was the way I was adding nodes back to the nodeset: nodeset << node... Worked with this: doc.root.add_child(node) instead. Thank you!